# Spark processing for statistical analysis of items with a duration

Tags: scala, sorting, apache-spark, apache-spark-sql, user-defined-functions

I have a spark data frame with items that have a certain duration; they go up at "start" and end at "stop".

```
id|start|stop |type| value
1 | 100 | 300 | A | 4.0
2 | 100 | 200 | B | 3.0
3 | 120 | 122 | A | 3.0
4 | 125 | 220 | A | 2.5
5 | 140 | 600 | B | 3.5 
1 | 150 | 700 | A | 4.0
2 | 220 | 300 | B | 3.0
3 | 230 | 401 | A | 3.0
4 | 232 | 400 | A | 2.5
5 | 310 | 311 | B | 3.5
```

Now I would like to calculate the mean (or later something more involved) for every of all the active ids for every time something changes. The problem is, that the original data set is about 30Mio lines, so I do need to use spark (2.0)

A brute force approach like (here written in pandas-like pseudo-code) is very inefficient:

```
Result = []
for type, subDf in df.groupby("type"): #for every type

    # get all times where chages happen
    changeTimes = union( subDf["start"], subDf["stop"]).sort()

    #loop through all times where an item starts or stops
    for t in changeTimes:

        # filter out all the active items
        subDfTime = subDf[ sunDF.start < t && sunDF.stop > t ]

        # calculate their mean
        result = subDfTime.value.mean()

        # return the time, the type and the mean of the values
        Result.append( [time, type, result] )
```

The original data is scanned very often for the active items (the ones which start before and stop after the given time). so the 30 Million items have to be scanned 60 Million times (as each one has a start and end time point)

Two ideas how to render this more efficient are:

1: to make two sorted data frames with the id and the start/stop times and then use a "search sorted" on these two lists and a union on the resulting indices

```
Result = []
for type, subDf in df.groupby("type"): #for every type

    # get all times where chages happen
    start_times = subDf[["id", "start"]].sort_values("start")
    stop_times  = subDf[["id", "stop"]].sort_values("stop")
    changeTimes = union( subDf["start"], subDf["stop"]).sort()

    #loop through all times where an item starts or stops
    for t in changeTimes:
        #get the index at which the time t would fit into start_times
        start_sort_index = start_times.search_sorted(t)
        #take out all the ids whose start time was before t
        start_ids = start_times["id"][start_sort_index:]  

        #do the analogous thing for end times
        stop_sort_index = stop_times.search_sorted(t)
        stop_ids = stop_times["id"][:stop_sort_index] 

        valid_ids_t = intersection( start_ids, stop_ids)
        # filter out all the active items
        subDfTime = subDf.index( valid_ids_t )

        # calculate their mean
        result = subDfTime.value.mean()

        # return the time, the type and the mean of the values
        Result.append( [time, type, result] )
```

so this idea rests on search sorted which should be log(N) operations and then indexing the original data frame via an index which should also be log(N). So I'm guessing this should be faster (and in pandas it actually is)

2: The second idea rests on sorting the start and stop times and iterating through them -- each time either taking in a new item (if it is a start time) or removing an item (if it is a stop time). (I've already asked how this could be done in spark and got a good [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47273346/how-can-i-loop-through-a-spark-data-frame))

so this idea would work something like this:

```
Result = []
for type, subDf in df.groupby("type"): #for every type

    # get all times where cahnges happen and add a direction 
    # true for an id getting in, false for an id popping out
    start_times = subDf[["id", "start"]].rename("start", "time")
    start_times["direction"] = true
    stop_times = subDf[["id", "stop"]].rename("stop", "time")
    stop_times["direction"] = false

    #sort the united list by time
    changeTimes= union( start_times, stop_times ).sort_values("time")

    #set of ids that are valid for each loop
    valid_ids_t = Set([])

    for id,time,direction in changeTimes:
        #if direction is true it means we are looking at a starting 
        #time and this we put the id in the list 
        #(==true is unnecessarily explicit I know, but it is explicit)
        if direction == true: valid_ids + id
        #if not it is a stop time and thus we remove it from the list
        else: valid_ids - id

        # filter out all the active items
        subDfTime = subDf.index( valid_ids_t )

        # calculate their mean
        result = subDfTime.value.mean()

        # return the time, the type and the mean of the values
        Result.append( [time, type, result] )
```

So my question is, which of these techniques could work for scala/spark? is there a "search_sorted" method? Is there a more efficient way to filter a spark data frame by an index than brute force ".filter()" (maybe with some sort of hash index) because that takes a really long time for a single item:

```
val fset = List(18850L, 30929L, 46538L, 50405L, 57596L, 59917L)
subDf.filter( $"id".isin(fset: _*) ).show()
```

as well as

```
subProp.filter( $"startTime" < lit(30642238068L) && $"stopTime" > lit(30642238068L) ).show()
```

For parallelism it would be perfectly fine if each "groupBy('type')" was to be run on a single worker -- this does not need to be parallelized.

I'm also grateful for other hints -- this seems like a problem that might have been solved before, but apparently I'm lacking the right terms, names and context for a successful google search.

Comment: If something is incomprehensible please tell me and I will improve the question. I know it is not a simple transformation I'm trying to solve.

Comment: I think your problem statement is clear. I understand the two approaches you described (I am not sure about what is intended by the statement `if direction == true: valid_ids + id else: valid_ids + id` though). Interested as well to know how to translate your implementation in Spark! :-)

Comment: @Alexandre thanks for the question and finding the bug. I've added some comments to make it clearer